# Display only such root level categories that either have any products or their subcategories have any products

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please tell me, there are 2 tables:

1 - table of categories, and links (cat2 and cat3 are subject to cat1)

```
prod_category
id|name|parent_category|
1 |cat1|       0       |
2 |cat2|       1       |
3 |cat3|       1       |
4 |cat4|       3       |
5 |cat5|       3       |
6 |cat6|       0       |
7 |cat7|       6       |
8 |cat8|       0       |
9 |cat9|       8       |
10|cat10|      9       |
```

2 - table of products and their categories

```
products
id| name|category_id|
1 |prod1|     0     |
2 |prod2|     1     |
3 |prod3|     2     |
4 |prod4|     3     |
5 |prod5|     4     |
6 |prod6|     5     |
7 |prod7|     6     |
8 |prod8|     7     |
9 |prdo9|     8     |
10|prod10|    9     |
```

I am doing sql parent category loop:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM prod_category WHERE parent_category='0'");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
if ($count_products_in_category > 0) {
echo $row['name'];
}
else {}
}
```

Next, I need to calculate whether this category is fixed in the products (whether there are products in it). If not, then take the category that is subordinate (child) and count whether there are products in it, and until the end of the relationship. If there are products in any category (child or in the parent itself), then display `$row['name']`, if not, then do not display.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of subcategory levels? If there is, than you can create a loop for the maximum number of layers, if not you should do it recursively

Comment: @kiks73 Unfortunately, no, it can be 10 or 100.

Answer (score -2):

Three steps

#### SQL

Get all categories with count of products

```
select c.id, c.parent, c.name, count(p.id) cnt from categories c 
left join products p on p.cat_id=c.id 
group by c.id
```

#### PDO

use that special PDO ability to return the array indexed by the first field, id in our case

```
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

#### PHP

Now for each category, go up to the root, the same way I showed you before

```
$roots = [];
foreach ($data as $cat) {
    $cnt = 0;
    do {
        $cnt += $cat['cnt'];
        $cat = $data[$cat['parent']];
    } while($cat['parent']);

    $roots[$cat['id']] = $cat;
    $roots[$cat['id']]['has_products'] ?? 0;
    $roots[$cat['id']]['has_products'] = max((bool)$cnt, $roots[$cat['id']]['has_products']);
}
```

it should give you an array with root categories, each having a flag, whether it has any products or not.

With a more versatile category structure implementation, such as Materialized path, it would be possible to get all the required data in one SQL query

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where p.category=c.id group by c.id'

Comment: sure, i forgot the ON clause

Comment: can't you do it yourself? do you understand SQL joins?

Comment: unfortunately I'm new to this.